# Insert the environment path to script file to read

Tags: shell, init.d

I have a text file which has user input i.e `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I want to add that id's library path environment text into the script file (example: /etc/init.d/scriptfilename).

Will it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only one environment variable in the file.

```
# cat file1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Now, in your script, read this to a value to a variable and then use `printenv` command to get its value. Example :

```
var1=$(cat file1)
printenv ${var1}
```

If you have more env variables in the file, you will have to step through each env variable name.